# React AutoSuggest: search text box not updating on suggestion selection

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, autocomplete

I am using the react [autosuggest](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) library to build auto-suggestion

```
import Autosuggest from "react-autosuggest";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import QueryString from "query-string";

class AutoSuggestSearch extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      suggestions: []
    };
    this.getSuggestionValue = this.getSuggestionValue.bind(this);
    this.renderSuggestion = this.renderSuggestion.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };

  getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.fullNameSuggestion;


  renderSuggestion = suggestion => <div>{suggestion.name}</div>;

  onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestion}) => {
    console.log(suggestion);
    this.setState({
      suggestions: [],
      value: suggestion.name
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    const params = {
      stationPrefixName: value
    };
    const queryParams = QueryString.stringify(params);
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/suggest?${queryParams}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          suggestions: data
        });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  };

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to clear suggestions.
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: [],
      value: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: "Search",
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };


    return (
      <Autosuggest
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
        getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default AutoSuggestSearch;
```

The suggestion gets rendered on typing on search box as well as the logging inside onSuggestionSelected gets logged correctly but the input search box does not update correctly.

On debugging further I found that `onSuggestionsClearRequested` also gets invoked after `onSuggestionSelected` which is causing the search input box to be empty.

I validated this by adding const string inside `onSuggestionsClearRequested`

```
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    alert("clear request");
    this.setState({
      suggestions: [],
      value: "mysearch"
    });
  };
```

Is there anyway to prevent `onSuggestionsClearRequested` invokation on suggestion selection?
Or updating the search query value inside `onSuggestionsClearRequested` is the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentDidUpdate or UseEffect if you are using it in functional component.

I have used `react-autosuggest` in functional component and clear suggestion works only if value doesn't matches with the suggestions:

```
const [clear, setClear] = useState(false);
const handleOnChange = newValue => {
  setValue(newValue);
  setClear(false);
};
useEffect(() => {
  if (!suggestions.some(option => option === value) && clear) {
    setValue('');
  }
}, [clear]);

const onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
  setClear(true);
  setSuggestions([]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onSuggestionsClearRequested` function gets called everytime you click outside the search input, which is the default implementation of the libary being used,

What we implement in `onSuggestionsClearRequested` is upto us.
you can change the implementation as follows :
Approach keep keyword inside input if available options are not selected

```
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {};
```

this should provide the desired implementation behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may approach with hooks. It looks good and less coding.

You may find below

https://github.com/rajmaravanthe/react-auto-suggestion

Comment: This is irrelevant.